# strstr() equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, algorithm, strstr

I have two `byte[]` and I want to find the first occurrence of the second `byte[]` in the first `byte[]` (or a range in it).

I don't want to use strings for efficiency (translating the first `byte[]` to a `string` will be inefficient).

Basically I believe that's what `strstr()` does in C.

What is the best way to do that (so it be efficient and easy to use)?

This is how it should look like:

```
int GetOffsetOfArrayInArray(byte[] bigArray, int bigArrayOffset, int bigArrayCount, byte[] smallArray);
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I want a solution that would be more efficient than a simple search. This means that using the fact that comparing buffers can be more efficient should be used - **memcmp() is more efficient than iterating over the bytes**.

Also, I know there are algorithms that optimize scenarios like this one:

- big array: "12312351231234"
- small array: "1231234"
- **Naive algorithm:** 7 compares to find that "1231235" is different than "1231234", 2 compares to find the next "1", 4 compares to find that "1235" is different than "1231", 3 compares to find the next "1", 7 compares to find match. A total of 7+2+4+3+7=23 compares.
- **Smart algorithm:** 7 compares to find that "1231235" is different than "1231234", directly jumps to the next "1" (without comparing), 4 compares to find that "1235" is different than "1231", directly jumps beyond the "5", 7 compares to find the match. A total of 7+4+7=18 compares.

Comment: First, code it with the conversion, then profile it.  If you find it to be in your performance bottleneck, only then optimize it so you don't have the conversion.  Wrap your check in a function call so you can simply replace the implementation later if you have to optimize it.

Comment: memcmp() is *not* an alternative for strstr().  The standard CRT doesn't have the function that you are looking for.  You can just pinvoke strstr() from msvcrt.dll, available on any version of Windows.  It will however not tolerate a byte[] that contains a zero.

Comment: "memcmp() is more efficient than iterating over the bytes" - if (and only if) it is implemented under the covers to do word-sized comparisons or use special features of the hardware. Trying to optimize memcmp where the input buffers start on different alignments is quite... fiddly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any code for you but the name of the fastest solution you will find is the [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) algorithm. It can do better than O(n).

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/BoyerMooreSearch.aspx) is an implementation for strings on CodeProject. Looks like a conversion to `byte[]` should not be too difficult.

Comment: An implementation of this in .NET would be great. But also the usage of memcmp to do fast compares would help...

Comment: "Better than O(n)" requires some caveats. *If* the lengths of the two strings are related, so that the target string length is proportional to the length of the string being searched, *and* your input is constrained to best cases, *then* it's constant-time. Worst case is O(n): better than the O(n*m) worst case of the naive search.

Answer (score 1):

```
int GetOffsetOfArrayInArray(byte[] bigArray, int bigArrayOffset, 
                               int bigArrayCount, byte[] smallArray)
{
     byte first = smallArray[0];
     bool cont= true;
     while (cont && 
            bigArrayOffset=Array.IndexOf(bigArray, first, bigArrayOffset) != -1)
     {
         if (bigArrayOffset + smallArray.Length > bigArray.Length)
         {
              bigArrayOffset = -1;
              break;
         }
         cont= false;
         for(int i=1; i< smallArray.Length; ++i)
         {
              if (bigArray[bigArrayOffset+i] != smallArray[i])
              { 
                 ++bigArrayOffset;
                 cont = true;
                 break;
              }
         }
     }
     return bigArrayOffset;
}
```

UPDATED; (hopefully) Fixed problem Henk alerted me to.

UPDATE 2: Addressing update to original question:

```
int GetOffsetOfArrayInArray(byte[] bigArray, int bigArrayOffset, 
                               int bigArrayCount, byte[] smallArray)
{
     int bigArrayEnd = Math.Min(bigArrayCount + bigArrayOffset, bigArray.Length)
     byte first = smallArray[0];
     bool cont= true;
     while (cont && 
            bigArrayOffset=Array.IndexOf(bigArray, first, bigArrayOffset) != -1)
     {
         int bookmark = bigArrauOffset + 1;
         bool bookmarkset = false;
         if (bigArrayOffset + smallArray.Length > bigArrayEnd )
         {
              bigArrayOffset = -1;
              break;
         }
         cont= false;
         for(int i=1; i< smallArray.Length; ++i)
         {
              if (!bookmarkset && bigArray[bigArrayOffset+i] == first)
              {
                   bookmark = bigArrayOffset+i;
                   bookmarkset = true;
              }
              if (bigArray[bigArrayOffset+i] != smallArray[i])
              { 
                 bigArrayOffset = bookmark;
                 cont = true;
                 break;
              }
         }
     }
     return bigArrayOffset;
}
```

Comment: I voted +1 but I think it won't work (the `continue` applies to the `for` loop, you want it for the `while`).

Comment: Just a detail: bigArrayCount is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on a solution. It's split in two. The first part mainly searches for a potential start. If it finds one it the compares the list from both ends (to lower the loop count which is basically a micro optimization with out a profiler but *usually* it's faster)

```
int GetOffsetOfArrayInArray(byte[] bigArray,
                        int bigArrayOffset,
                        int bigArrayCount,
                        byte[] smallArray)
    {
        var length = smallArray.Length;
        var lastPossibleStart = bigArray.Length - length;
        var startByte = smallArray[0];

        for (var first = bigArrayOffset; first < lastPossibleStart; first++)
        {
           if (bigArray[first] == startByte &&
               check(bigArray, smallArray, first, length))
           {
              return first;
           }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    bool check(byte[] bigArray, byte[] smallArray, int first, int length)
    {
        var smallIndex = 0;
        var smallLast = length - 1;
        var last = first + length - 1;
        for (var i = first; smallIndex <= smallLast; i++)
        {
            if (bigArray[i] != smallArray[smallIndex] ||
                 bigArray[last] != smallArray[smallLast])
            {
                return false;
            }
            smallIndex = i - first + 1;
            last--;
            smallLast--;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has multiple compile errors. When they're fixed in what seems like the most likely intended way, it suffers from an array out-of-bounds bug.

Comment: yeah a few compile errors there, nut I must be "code blind" I can't see the a-o-b

Comment: How about `smallArray[first - bigArrayOffset]`? For simplicity suppose we're searching the whole big array so `bigArrayOffset` is zero. Hence it's just `smallArray[first]`, where `first` is clearly going to get too big if the short pattern doesn't occur soon enough in the big array.

Answer (score 0):

In algorithm theory, it is well known that optimizing for speed costs memory and vice versa. My algorithm uses a bit more memory (not much) but in return only scans the big array once.

```
public static int GetOffsetOfArrayInArray(byte[] bigArray, int bigArrayOffset, int bigArrayCount, byte[] smallArray)
{
    // TODO: Check whether none of the variables are null or out of range.
    if (smallArray.Length == 0)
        return 0;

    List<int> starts = new List<int>();    // Limited number of elements.

    int offset = bigArrayOffset;
    // A single pass through the big array.
    while (offset < bigArrayOffset + bigArrayCount)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < starts.Count; i++)
        {
            if (bigArray[offset] != smallArray[offset - starts[i]])
            {
                // Remove starts[i] from the list.
                starts.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
            else if (offset - starts[i] == smallArray.Length - 1)
            {
                // Found a match.
                return starts[i];
            }
        }
        if (bigArray[offset] == smallArray[0] &&
            offset <= (bigArrayOffset + bigArrayCount - smallArray.Length))
        {
            if (smallArray.Length > 1)
                // Add the start to the list.
                starts.Add(offset);
            else
                // Found a match.
                return offset;
        }
        offset++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The list `starts` is used to track potential start offsets of `smallArray` in `bigArray`. It will never contain more elements than the number of occurrences of `smallArray[0]` in `smallArray` (which may be calculated in advance to optimize the list and reduce the number of memory reallocations). When there are not enough bytes left in `bigArray` to contain `smallArray`, it is not tried, and when `smallArray` has been found, the algorithm stops. It also stops when the end of `bigArray` has been reached. Therefor, the worst case running time would be O(1), and the memory usage would be O(1).

Further possible optimizations include using pointers in unsafe code, and replacing the list by a fixed array whose size can be calculated in advance (as noted before). However, because in the list wrong offsets are removed (smaller inner loop) and in an array wrong offsets have to be skipped (fixed size inner loop but possibly faster element access), you'd have to benchmark which one is faster.

It also matters whether you expect `smallArray` to be large or not. When you do, you could add a check to the while loop which checks whether `starts.Length != 0 || offset <= (bigArrayOffset + bigArrayCount - smallArray.Length)`. Otherwise the loop may stop and no occurrences have been found.