# What is the C# equivalent to strstr() in C?

Tags: c#, c

First of all, there is a question title that almost exactly matches my question ([strstr() equivalent in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536958/strstr-equivalent-in-c-sharp)), but he's referring to a method to do a byte[] comparison version.

I'm looking for a string comparison that outputs the index of the first occurance of str2 in str1, and just cannot find it!

```
string s1 = ("BetYouCantFooFind");
string s2 = ("Foo");

int idx = strstrC#(s1,s2);
```

Surely there is an equivalent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx):

```
int idx = s1.IndexOf(s2);
```

Comment: C#: coming from a C background, I find this language to be the hardest easiest language in the world.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Coming from C, the main vice will be that you should think in objects instead of stand-alone functions. So if something has to do with a certain type, it is usually a member of that type. Visual Studio is your friend: Instantiate an object of a type, then add a '.' and simply scroll through the methods.... That helped me get going at first when starting out in C#

Answer (score 7):

```
var s1 = "BetYouCantFooFind";
var s2 = "Foo";
var idx = s1.IndexOf(s2); // Returns -1 if not found
```

Answer (score 4):

```
        Console.WriteLine("BoboTheClown".IndexOf("boT"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed this old post and would like to extend the answer. If you don't care for the case like when you use in C `memicmp` or `stricmp` then you extend the `IndexOf` in C# this way.

```
int idx = s1.IndexOf(s2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```